# can't use Session in a class that is using inherited in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I've created a webpage which is inherited from another class something like :

```
class webpage : startup {
.
.
.
}


class startup :  System.Web.UI.Page  {

}
```

and inside startup class I'm trying to use

```
Session["blah"] = "some other blah";
```

but whenever I run this code I'll get the following error :

> Session state can only be used when
>   enableSessionState is set to true,
>   either in a configuration file or in
>   the Page directive. Please also make
>   sure that
>   System.Web.SessionStateModule or a
>   custom session state module is
>   included in the
>   \\
>   section in the application
>   configuration.

I'll get error even after changing web.config to accept Session but again the same result
------------------------edit--------------------

I know I can use Httpcontext.current.session but this approad also give me error saying :
"you can't use null instance or something like that"
what should I do?

Comment: Do sessions work okay in other pages?  This kind of sounds like a configuration issue.  Also, could it be you're off in another thread?  (or maybe you weren't called from a page event?)

Comment: yeah session works as usual directly from .aspx files or even from global.asax but not inside the other classes :( by the way I'm using IIS 6.0 and .net 4.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've created a `BasePage` class as follows:

```
namespace JWC.Examples.WebForms.Base {
   public class BasePage: Page {
   }
}
```

And a default page that inherits from `BasePage`:

```
namespace JWC.Examples.WebForms {
   public partial class _Default : BasePage {
      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
         if (Session["SomeItem"] == null)
            Session["SomeItem"] = 42;
      }
   }
}
```

I have no problems accessing session at all. Not sure what the issue is, but having inherited from another class beside Page is most likely a red herring.

This one is going to be difficult to diagnose without including a lot of details. The best advice I can give is to create a blank ASP.Net project, and start porting things over one by one so you can eliminate possibilities systematically.

### UPDATE

[Mr. Powers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205463/austin-powers) was kind enough to send me a test solution that recreated the problem.

The issue lies within the idiosyncrasies of the [ASP.Net Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx). The offending code looked something like this:

```
public class BasePage: Page
{
    public BasePage()
    {
        //Do some stuff with Session
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, trying to access Session in the constructor is a non-starter because the Request and Response objects aren't set until after the constructor is called. The trick is to move your code into a stage where those things have been initialized, but before other dependent code might need to take advantage of it.

The [PreInit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.preinit.aspx) event will do the trick. If you get rid of the constructor, and override the OnPreInit event, then everything should be fine. Like this:

```
protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreInit(e);

    //Do some stuff with Session
}
```

Understanding the Page lifecycle is a critical component to doing anything in ASP.Net. One should read the MSDN documentation thoroughly before proceeding any further with Web Forms as it will save many a headache down the road.

Comment: I have created a new project something like yours even with a more clean web.config but same result :-?

Comment: If you want you can zip up a solution and email it to me. That may be the only way to really troubleshoot the problem, as it may be machine specific.

Comment: still I have the same problem even in IIS7 and I couldn't find any email of you this is mine :  wisdomtooth84@gmail.com please email me so I can send you my project. regards

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
class webpage : startup {
   …
}

class startup :  System.Web.UI.Page  {
    protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreInit(e);
        var session = HttpContext.Current.Session["...."];
    }
}
```

So the session is not in the constructor of the `Startup`, but in the override of `OnPreInit` instead.